# Call MVC Controller from AngularJS in ASP.Net MVC with web API controller

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a project that uses ASP.NET MVC, AngularJS and WebAPI 2.0. I am calling a mvc controller from AngularJS. I am getting an error in the call to a MVC controller from AngularJS.

**Model**

```
public class HotelPayment
{
    public string TransactionID { get; set; }
    public string Referencenumber { get; set; }
    public string destination { get; set; }
    public string hotelname { get; set; }
    public string hoteladdress { get; set; }
    public string board { get; set; }
    public string noofrooms { get; set; }
    public string checkin { get; set; }
    public string checkout { get; set; }
}
```

**MVC Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public string Sendpayment(HotelPayment objData)
{
   Session["products"] = objData;
   return objData.url;
}
```

**Call MVC methord** from anguler controller.

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    data: paymentData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Home/Sendpayment"
});
```

I'm getting this error.
[image]

Why am I seeing this? My MVC controller and API are controller in the same project. Is there anything to do with this error?

Comment: Have you tried to debug in the method `Sendpayment`, the http status code 500 indicate that the server encountered an error while processing the request.

Comment: There is a problem in Server side which we can't guess it, Catch the exception and log details to get more info,Use `try-catch`.

Comment: When debug in localhost it work fine. But after hosing cloud i get this error.

Comment: First check the service so try postman for test service.

Comment: Can you please post your HotelPayment object here to understand more

Comment: postman response also error. "An error occurred while processing your request."

Comment: The problem occurs only for this method?

Comment: Think about what the method does, and what things it needs in order to work. Presumably there is some difference between your local environment and the hosted environment which isn't set up to allow what's necessary. I'm thinking things like file/folder access, database setup, commands available, DLLs installed etc. I don't know exactly because I can't see your error message or full code. Check your server's logs to get the exact exception method, and also show the MVC method if you need more help. Having an Web API controller in the same project is a valid thing and is not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error using Enabling Cross-Origin Requests (CORS).

[Enabling Cross-Origin Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors)